# Setting mode in emacs

Tags: elisp

I have several bash scripts that output SQL. 99% of the time I want emacs to edit it in sql-mode. I inserted this into my .emacs file:

`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sql\\.sh\\'" . sql-mode))`

I get the right mode if I open a non-existing file like 'foobar.sql.sh' within emacs. However, if I open an existing file that has `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, I get shell-script-mode. How do I change it so that I get sql-mode?

Comment: It could be that magic-mode-alist is taking precedent over auto-mode-alist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your `interpreter-mode-alist` variable, you'll find an entry like `("r?bash2?" . sh-mode)` or `("bash" . sh-mode)` depending on which version of emacs you're running. This setting takes precedence over `magic-mode-alist` and `auto-mode-alist`.

I suggest removing that entry from `interpreter-mode-alist`, getting rid of the new entry you added to `auto-mode-alist`, and adding two new entries to `magic-mode-alist` instead:

```
(add-to-list 'magic-mode-alist '("r?bash2?" . sh-mode))
(add-to-list 'magic-mode-alist
  '((lambda ()
      (string-match "\\.sql\\.sh$" (buffer-file-name))) . sql-mode))
```

Be sure to add them in this order so the second one is in front of the first one in the resulting list (and yes, there are other ways of doing this but I'm showing it this way for clarity). The second entry, which will be tried first, checks the buffer name to see if it matches a `.sql.sh` suffix and sets `sql-mode` if so. If that match fails, the other entry checks the beginning of the buffer for the same pattern `interpreter-mode-alist` was looking for and sets `sh-mode` if it matches.

Comment: Works for me on emacs 22.1.1. I deleted the entry using `(delete '("bash" . sh-mode) interpreter-mode-alist)`